# How can I use a secret on Repl.it with my JavaScript code for Telegram using Telegraf?

Tags: javascript, replit

I have this code:

```
const bot = new Telegraf('tokengoeshereblablablabla')
```

And I want it to look like this:

```
const bot = new Telegraf(TOKEN)
```

So my Telegram token wont be leaked. I know it's possible, but I don't find it eather here in StackOverflow either Google.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In repl.it you can set your secret variables in specific section
Look at this image below you can set key as TOKEN and value [YOURTOKEN]
[image]

Simply you can use it in nodejs file like:

```
const bot = new Telegraf(process.env.TOKEN)
```

Note: if you can't access it like above line, you will need to install dotenv package to load environment variables.

Comment: Testing it right now! Will update if working! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Apparently, I'm having another error. I've created a Pastebin so I could attach this somehow. Installed dotenv using "npm i dotenv" but neither: https://pastebin.com/0szvzz02

Comment: I think in repl.it you can use environment variables in your code without intstalling `dotenv` package.

Comment: Before you use your secret variable, try to print it using `console.log(process.env.TOKEN)` to make sure the token is accessable.

Comment: Ok, so I found a workaround. It seems like you need to sort of define the 'TOKEN' value when you run your bot.js file and so be like this: "BOT_TOKEN='123456789:AbCdfGhIJKlmNoQQRsTUVwxyZ' npm start".

Comment: Just saw your previous message. Nope, it still fails when I type it at the beggining of the program. Seems like a Repl.it permission thing, because for the bot, it seems like it does not have rights to access that string of text.

Comment: What is the message error it shows up ?

Comment: This one: https://pastebin.com/0szvzz02 but I managed to fix it using the "BOT_TOKEN='123456789:AbCdfGhIJKlmNoQQRsTUVwxyZ' npm start".

Comment: Hey there again! I don't know why, but now it's working without indicating that attribute on the command string. Thanks a lot for the provided support! (:

Comment: @Rodri  Don't mention it, you are welcome!